# User authentication from applet

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, applet, slim

First of all - I'm not really into web developping, so please be gentle ;)
I've got a simple request from my friend to create an applet that displays to user some personalized data and allows adding new values to database. The problem is to log the user in. I had such idea of my system:

- applet
- WebService accessing the database (based on Slim framework)
- database.

Applet would access only WebService. Connection via https to be safe. 
In database, in table 'users' I'd store username, hashed password and salt. However I do not want to send user credentials with every call to database. It may be unsafe. What should I do to make it safe?

==== Edit =====
Or maybe it's enough to use HTTPS + Basic Authentication?

Answer (score 2):

The problem of using basic authentication is that you will have to hard-code the credentials within the applet it self. This is not recommended for many reasons especially if it's going to be a front-end / enduser applet as they can fairly easily get those credentials which means you've just gave them a valid OS account on the Web Server.

Just use simple session management with cookies or tokens. The user is authenticated once and then the session identifier is sent with every request, while the session is valid on the web-service it will accept the request as valid.